# Error while FTPing files

Tags: bash, unix, ftp

I'm getting the following error while executing the script. Don't know where I'm getting it wrong.

Error message:

```
./ftp_send_script.sh: line 40: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Here is the script

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

#Define Variables
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

HOST=qftpserver
USER=ftpuser
PASS=password

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#FTP files
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
for FILE in `ls *.txt`
do
        ftp -n -p << EOT
        open $HOST
        user $USER $PASS
        prompt n
        type binary
        mput ${FILE}
        quit
        EOT
echo ${FILE}
done
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the terminator in a heredoc must be at the BEGINNING on a line, not indented:

```
for FILE in `ls *.txt`
        ...
        mput ${FILE}
        quit
        EOT
```

should be

```
for FILE in `ls *.txt`
     ...
     mput ${FILE}
     quit
EOT    <---start in column 0, not indented.
```

Since yours is indented, the heredoc is actually not terminated, and the shell parser simply runs off the end of the script, hence your `unexpected end of file`

Comment: It worked. I didn't know that indented makes a difference. Thanks.

Comment: a heredoc terminator must be on a line by itself, and any text on that line is considered part of that terminator string. so you actually had `[tab][tab]EOT` (or [space]. whatever you were using), where the shell was looking for `EOT`. Since it never saw a bare `EOT`, the heredoc never closed and you ran off the bottom of the script.